# Yamaha digital piano USB to Host with RaspberryPi issue

Tags: usb-audio

I bought a Yamaha CLP 685 to learn how to play piano. I learned that this piano also can connect to a host to act as a DAC + active speakers, so I sold my DAC, amp and the passive speakers to save space and money.

It works fine with macOS, I can use the USB port for both audio input and MIDI.

However, when I connect it to a RaspberryPi 3 running Volumio, the piano will be silent after around 8 minutes. I can try pause and play again from Volumio then it will play again, but after about 8 minutes, it will stop just like before. The piano will also shut down itself as if it didn't detect any USB connect after 15 minutes.

I tried a different system on the RaspberryPi 3 called Runeaudio, it uses ArchLinux instead of Debian, but it gives the same results.

Do anyone know anything about this issue?

Comment: what happens if you send a midi event to the piano before the 8 minute timeout?

Comment: your question is not related to the RPi ... you may have better luck searching sites related to Linux